# how can i include python.h in QMake

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, qt, qmake

> INCLUDEPATH = -L /usr/include/python2.7
>
> LIBS += /usr/local/lib/python2.7
>
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /usr/local/lib/python2.7

```
error: cannot find /usr/local/lib/python2.7: File format not recognized
```

There is a problem.
I have already installed python-all-dev.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the following format:

```
LIBS += -L {path of your library.so} -l{library}    
INCLUDEPATH += {path of your headers} 
DEPENDPATH += {path of your headers}
```

In your case:

```
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python2.7
DEPENDPATH += /usr/include/python2.7
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html